# Is there a satisfactory resolution to the Rotating Detector Puzzle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, unruh-effect

The Rotating Detector Puzzle refers to the dilemma when trying to study how a rotating detector interacts with the background vacuum. The trail of literature that I found are these papers: [p1](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996PhRvD..53.4382D), [p2](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9612006), [p3](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/18/9/313), [p4](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0406080) and a few others (This one is the most recent so far: [p5](http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv11i30p63.pdf)).

What is the status of the problem? Is there an agreement that the rotating detector will interact with the vacuum and that there is no proper ground state?